# How to generate momentjs format from custom time object

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

**Context:**

Hi, I am trying to generate a `moment.js format` from the given start time and end time.

```
let sourceTime = {
  "startTime": "0600", // 6 AM
  "endTime": "2100" // 9 PM
}
```

Using the above endTime property I am trying to get time in the format below :

> 2021-02-04T09:00 pm
> i.e This format  https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/    - "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm a"

using this piece of code

```
let currentDate = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
let savedFormat = moment(`${currentDate} ${sourceTime.endTime.substring(0, 2)}:${sourceTime.endTime.substring(2, 4)}`).format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm')
```

Where I am adding the current date and end time in a customized way using a string literal to generate the desired format.

**Problem:**

I am getting 9:00 am instead of 9:00 pm.

> 2021-02-04T09:00 am

Not sure where I'm doing wrong. Any suggestion would be helpful.

```js
let sourceTime = {
  "startTime": "0600", // 6 AM
  "endTime": "2100" // 9 PM
}

let currentDate = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
let savedFormat = moment(`${currentDate} ${sourceTime.endTime.substring(0, 2)}:${sourceTime.endTime.substring(2, 4)}`).format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm')

console.log(savedFormat);

//Shows am instead of pm
console.log(moment(savedFormat).format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm a'));
//OUTPUT
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting [Momentjs Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), I would propose the following solution:

```js
let sourceTime = {
  "startTime": "0600", // 6 AM
  "endTime": "2100" // 9 PM
}
const startTime = moment(sourceTime.startTime, 'HHmm').format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm a');
const endTime = moment(sourceTime.endTime, 'HHmm').format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm a');

console.log(startTime + ' to ' + endTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Worked after slight modification in this format. Thanks                                                           
                                                                                                                                         
 const startTime = moment(sourceTime1.startTime, 'HHmm').format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm a');
const endTime = moment(sourceTime1.endTime, 'HHmm').format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm a');

console.log(startTime + ' to ' + endTime);

Answer (score 1):

Try the below example to see if it works

```js
console.log(
    moment('Mon 03-Jul-2017, 11:00 AM', 'ddd DD-MMM-YYYY, hh:mm A')
    .format('hh:mm A')
);
```

```js
console.log(
    moment('Mon 03-Jul-2017, 11:00 PM', 'ddd DD-MMM-YYYY, hh:mm A')
    .format('hh:mm A')
);
```

Comment: 11:00 PM / 11:00 AM  - I think there is slight confusion here. I am trying to generate moment object from "2100" i.e from 24hrs format.